# Getting a path to overlap a rectangle or other control

Tags: wpf, path, geometry, overlap

I have the following XAML :

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <DockPanel Margin="5">
  <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="White" DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
      <Path.Data>
          <GeometryGroup>
              <LineGeometry StartPoint="10,0" EndPoint="0,10" />
              <LineGeometry StartPoint="0,10" EndPoint="10,20" />
          </GeometryGroup>
      </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Rectangle Stroke="Black" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10"/>
  </DockPanel>
</Page>
```

It creates like a speech bubble. However I would like the part where the two join to be white or not to have any stroke.

[image]

Comment: Draw white path where they intersect and in order to intersect you should use canvas, not the dockpanel

Comment: Does will the canvas still allow me to place wrappable text inside the bubble, also does it have any performance considerations?

Comment: Canvas does not have bounds unless you specify those, so wrappable textblock can be impossible to achieve unless you specify textblock width or height. Canvas is better in performance compared to container controls because it's layout logic is more simple. If you want to work with wrapable textblock with relative sizes, use Grid then and play with margins or negative margins to intersect those elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very clever, but perhaps sufficient:

```
<DockPanel Margin="5">
    <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"
          Fill="White" DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Panel.ZIndex="1" Margin="0,0,-1,0" Data="M10,0 L0,10 10,20"/>
    <Rectangle Stroke="Black" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10"/>
</DockPanel>
```

---

A better solution might be to create a `CombinedGeometry` from the Path and the Rectangle.

Comment: Why is this not very clever?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Blend you can use the `Callout` control, which does exactly what you want.
It resides in this assembly:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.0\Libraries\Microsoft.Expression.Drawing.dll
```

and is used like that:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

        <ed:Callout AnchorPoint="-0.061,0.716" CalloutStyle="RoundedRectangle" Content="Callout" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" FontSize="14.667" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="109" Margin="61,78,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="375"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: Screenshot]

**Edit:** if you have Blend (for VS 2012) you can easily draw a path yourself that looks like a callout.

Example:

```
<Path Data="M110.029,0.5 L305.895,0.5 C314.17927,0.50000358 320.895,7.2157323 320.895,15.500005 L320.895,144.202 C320.895,152.48627 314.17927,159.202 305.895,159.202 L110.029,159.202 C101.74473,159.202 95.028999,152.48627 95.029,144.202 L95.029,119.139 0.5,94.029644 94.530329,44.776012 95.029,69.723011 95.029,15.500005 C95.028999,7.2157323 101.74473,0.50000358 110.029,0.5 z" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="159.702" Margin="122.366,45.642,0,0" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="321.395"/>
```

Comment: I would have to deploy my application with this library? If so I am not sure it would be worth the hassle for just this one thing.

Comment: Yes that's right you'd have to deploy this file.
Have edited the answer to show an alternative ...